# Is it possible using .htaccess file to keep / and all links in a subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website example.com with a subdirectory of `example.com/admin/`, I want to put a .htaccess file in my `/admin/` directory so that if I create a link like this `<a href="/">Home</a>` that it will stay in `example.com/admin/` and not go to `example.com/`.

I know I could just do `<a href="/admin/">Home</a>`, but want an over all solution where I don't have to do that to all links, encase at a later time I decided to rename the `/admin/` directory.

Comment: This behavior can be achieved not from admin directory but from your root directory's .htaccess

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: You wrote: **I want to put a .htaccess file in my /admin/ directory** but that can only be done from DocumentRoot .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with .htaccess. Because it is not on the server that it happens, but in the browser.

But it is possible to redirect some pages, If it is possible to recognize them, for example by name.
You can redirect all `admin-xxxx.html` pages to `admin/admin-xxxx.html`